# How do I get S3 URLs for my Filestack uploads? I only see Filestack URLs

Tags: json, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am writing a javascript application using Filestack, and have configured it to upload to S3 storage. Where can I access the S3 URLs so that I can use the files?

Answer (score 3):

If your S3 bucket is publicly available, you can construct S3 URL from the 'key' Filestack is returning in the metadata of the Filestack FileLink.

For example this [link](https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/jh7ktWzgjKhFXORRO30X/metadata):

will return:

```
{
  "mimetype": "image/png",
  "uploaded": 1507326798793.528,
  "container": "bigbucket",
  "writeable": true,
  "filename": "rondo-thumb.png",
  "location": "S3",
  "key": "opd1KxrTaWg9MifibCew_rondo-thumb.png",
  "path": "opd1KxYTaWl9MifkbCew_rondo-thumb.png",
  "size": 173125
}
```

The region is not returned, assumption is you set the bucket up so you know the region and the bucket name.

Using this information, you can then construct the S3 URL based on the region your bucket is located [Here](http://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bigbucket/opd1KxrTaWg9MifibCew_rondo-thumb.png) :

Appending the 'key', or the path to the S3 region prefix will give you your will S3 URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Filepicker you can also use the disableStorageKey parameter. This will make it so that the file is appended directly to the path that you specified, without the uuid added before the filename.